# Showing $(a,b,c)=((a,b),c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble.  If I let $(a,b,c)=g$, then I have that $(a,b)=h\ge{g}$ and I know that $g|h$  So there exists an integer $k$ such that $h=gk$.   Finally, I know that $g|c,$ so there exists an integer $x$ such that $c=gx$

So now, i want to show that $((a,b),c)=g$.  So suppose $((a,b),c)=j$.  Then $$(h,c)=j \Rightarrow  (gk,c)=j \Rightarrow (gk,gx)=g(k,x)=j$$

Now I know that $g|j$, but I now have to show that $(k,x)=1.$  Can I make that assumption as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $d = (a,b,c)$. We show that $d | (a,b)$ and $d | c$ and that if $g|(a,b)$ and $g|c$ then $g|d$, and hence $d = ((a,b),c)$ (by the definition of the greatest common divisor):

Certainly $d|c$, and $d | (a,b)$ since $d|a,b,c$ by definition and $(a,b)|a,b$. Now if $g|(a,b)$ and $g|c$, $g|a,b,c$ so by definition of $d$, we have that $g|d$, so we're done.

(By the way, when I write e.g. $g|a,b,c$ I mean that $g|a$, $g|b$, and $g|c$.)

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Prove a stronger result:

> The set of common divisors of $a,b,c$ is the intersection of the set of common divisors of $a,b$ with the set of divisors of $c$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\quad d\mid (a_1,a_2) \iff d\mid a_1,a_2\quad\ [\color{#c00}{UP} =$ Universal Property of GCD]

Hence $\rm\ \  d\mid (a_1,a_2),a_3,a_4,\ldots\!\!\!\overset{\color{#c00}{UP}}\iff d\mid a_1,a_2,\,\ d\mid a_3,a_4,\ldots\!\!\iff d\mid a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\ldots$

Therefore $\rm\ (a_1,a_2),a_3,a_4,\ldots\,$ and $\rm\,\ a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\ldots\,$ have the same set $\rm\,S\,$ of common divisors $\,\rm d,\,$ hence they have the same *greatest* common divisor $\rm (= max\ S).\quad $  **QED**

Hence the *associativity* of GCD boils down to the associativity of AND (which is implicit in above, i.e. $\rm\ d\mid a,\,b,\ldots\,$ means $\rm\,d\mid a\,$ AND $\rm\,d\mid b,\ldots\,).$

Answer (score 0):

You know that $j$ is a factor of $c$.  Can you show that, since $j$ is a factor of $h$, $j$ must be a factor of $a$ and $b$ as well?